# Have devise timeout a period x  after entering a number of wrong passwords?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Would it be possible to have Devise timeout for say 10 minutes if you enter a password wrong 10 times? With timeout I mean it will not be possible to enter a new password for period X and getting a message stating you have to wait.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. add `:lockable` strategy to your model
2. add `config.unlock_strategy = :time`
3. add `config.lock_strategy = :failed_attempts`
4. add `config.maximum_attempts = 10`
5. add `config.unlock_in = 10.minutes` to `initializers/devise.rb`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see any tutorials or even wiki/FAQs on the devise github account. However the readme does mention the lockable module. See https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/lockable.rb